See all assets in one place
I have several bags of each token, these tokens are in several different places, and the worst thing is that there is an exchange that keeps the tokens. Because of the mess, I don't have a counter on my assets, and unless I want to make a transaction, I don't know if I will get my money or not. If the total amount of my assets are the same or in each wallet, it will be easier for me, for example, I have ethereum in several ether accounts, but it happened several times that I wanted to buy Gaz, I didn't have many ethereum addresses, and the transaction failed.

Is there a question or is this just about a complaint about centralised exchanges?
